# Algorithm for a 3d polygon container

Tags: algorithm, 3d, bounding-box

I am looking for the algorithm to go from here:
[image]

To here:
[image]

It's not really a bounding box, because it has some diagonals, neither voxelization, but any clue on what's the name of this algorithm and how to achieve it ?

Comment: What are you going to do with the resulting model?

Comment: My goal is to display in opengl a copy of a high-polygon mesh, but for performance reason, I need a simplified version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operation is usually called either "*mesh simplification*"  or "*mesh decimation*" (see [this](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-10-fall/LectureSlides/08_Simplification.pdf)). You can replace "*mesh*" with "*triangular mesh*", "*triangulation*", "*polygonal model*", and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Based just on your picture it looks like you want to perform some form of polygon simplification on the profile of the object. You could do something like:

1. Project the object onto a 2D surface to create a profile (e.g., if the z-axis is along the length of the car then project onto the x-z or y-z plane)
2. Apply a polygon simplification (e.g., [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull), or [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm)
3. Re-project the object into 3D by extending the profile to bound the original object.